# Search by multiple Tags only

Tags: product, product-list, navigation, tags

I think about ditching the category-tree in the frontend and let the user navigate through tags on my webshop. This would be possible since I don't have more than 100 products in simple categories.

I am looking for a solution to display products based on tag combinations, say www.myshop.com/tags/gold displays all products tagged with "gold" and www.myshop.com/gold+sale displays all products tagged with "gold" and "sale".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

So by default the block `Mage_Tag_Block_Product_Result` which does the displaying of the tag based product list only works with a single tag.

```
->addTagFilter($this->getTag()->getId())
```

But you could easily either extend the core Magento functionality to rewrite the building of the product collection.

Or simply create your own controller and block and build on top of the core functionality and changes this filter.

The add tag functionality is very simply a `where tag_id = X` and so you could build this to be whatever type of where you need.

```
/**
 * Set tag filter
 *
 * @param int $tagId
 * @return Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
public function addTagFilter($tagId)
{
    $this->getSelect()->where('relation.tag_id = ?', $tagId);
    $this->setFlag('distinct', true);
    return $this;
}
```